# Entry point for a js browser lib in package.json

Tags: javascript, html, npm, package.json

Suppose I have a tiny `js` *browser* library that I want to publish to npm (for example this [one](https://github.com/maslick/aplouder)). 
The library simply gets included in the html file with a `<script>` tag and then used normally within the html document (or another js):

```
<script src="aplouder.js"></script>

<script>
  var library = new Aplouder({...});
</script>
```

1. What shall I specify for the `main` parameter in the `package.json`?
2. Should I go for `browser` instead of `main` or don't specify either of those entirely?
3. OPTIONAL: *What if I had 2 `js` files (e.g. `es5` and `es6` variant) that I wanted to publish with the library, and it's for the user to decide which one they would use?*

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often times you want to distribute your `js` library both as an `npm` package, and as a browser library (old-fashioned way). One way to handle this is to treat your `js` lib as an npm package and provide a browser bundle in a `/dist` folder for those who don't rely on any build system a.k.a. `module bundler` (e.g. webpack, parcel, rollup, etc.)

However, if your module is meant to be used client-side, the `browser` field should be used instead of the `main` field. So, answering the question:

**1 and 2**: Use `browser`:

```
"browser": "src/aplouder.js"
```

**3:**  I recommend to stick with either of those: `es5` or `es6`, and not both, since you cannot have more than one `browser` keys in a json.

Answer (score 0):

**1 and 2:** Your app should be bundled with its dependencies in a `/build` folder

**3:** Your app should be bundled in es5 and es6 bundles

The bundles should be managed with [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), usually es6 files are stored in `/src` directory while bundles are stored in `/build` or `/dist` folder

[A nice article to get started publishing on NPM](https://hackernoon.com/publish-your-own-npm-package-946b19df577e)

Comment: what about ``main`` and ``browser``?

Comment: as per your answer: 1) it's a lib not an app, it has no dependencies 2) i have nothing to bundle, everything is contained within one simple ``js`` file. 3) how would you specify entry-points for es5 and es6 bundles? isn't it restricted to only one (entry-point)?

Comment: 1) App (or better to say component) or lib does not make any difference
2)  Webpack as you can read (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) let you configure multiple entry points for your app

Comment: Using webpack for such a small library (one class, no dependencies) would be an overkill  IMHO... Forget my 3) question for now.